# Find byte array in another byte array with tolerance C#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, bitmap

I want to write basic algorithm which will search bitmap in another bitmap. I have byte arrays with RGB values. At this moment I tried 'for' loops but my alorithm is a bit slow.

What I mean?

`13 53 53 12 43 32 23 32 12 43`
`15 50 32 53 12 69 43 105 32 86`

I want to find X and Y of

`14 45 33`
`55 14 71`

They are here:

`12 43 32`
`53 12 69`

So Y = 0 X = 4

But we just need some tolerance to find them.

Any tips how to do it fast?

My stupid code here:

```
for (int y = 0;y<bigData.Height-smallData.Height + 1;y++)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < bigData.Width - smallData.Width + 1; x++)
            {
                tx = x;
                int color1 = y * bigBmpStride;

                int bigColorB = bigBmpRgb[color1 + (x * 3)];
                int bigColorG = bigBmpRgb[color1 + (x * 3) + 1];
                int bigColorR = bigBmpRgb[color1 + (x * 3) + 2];

                int smallColorB, smallColorG, smallColorR;

                if (!move)
                {
                    int color2 = 0 * bigBmpStride;

                    smallColorB = bigBmpRgb[color2 + (0 * 3)];
                    smallColorG = bigBmpRgb[color2 + (0 * 3) + 1];
                    smallColorR = bigBmpRgb[color2 + (0 * 3) + 2];
                }
                else
                {
                    int color2 = tempY * bigBmpStride;

                    smallColorB = bigBmpRgb[color2 + (tempX * 3)];
                    smallColorG = bigBmpRgb[color2 + (tempX * 3) + 1];
                    smallColorR = bigBmpRgb[color2 + (tempX * 3) + 2];
                }

                if (IsInRange(bigColorB, smallColorB, tolerance) && IsInRange(bigColorG, smallColorG, tolerance) && IsInRange(bigColorR, smallColorR, tolerance))
                {
                    move = true;

                    if (tempY != 0)
                        Debug.WriteLine(tempX.ToString() + "|" + tempY.ToString() + "    " + smallData.Height + "|" + smallData.Width);

                    if (tempX == smallData.Height)
                        break;

                    tempX++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    move = false;
                    tempX = 0;
                    tempY = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (tempX == smallData.Height && tempY == smallData.Width)
            {
                ret = new Point(tx, y);
                Debug.WriteLine("found!!");
                found = true;
                break;
            }

            if (found)
                break;

            if (move)
            tempY++;

            else
            {
                tempY = 0;
                tempX = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show your slow code with the for loop. Update your question with a edit to include the code

Comment: Done. But this code is working 5/10. I really don't have any idea what I can do.

Comment: What's the context of the problem? Do you want to search many small pieces inside a big picture? Or search for the same small piece within many big pictures? Is it just a one-off thing? You could also consider doing a fast 2D cross correlation (using FFT) and then searching for the highest response the obvious way.

Comment: small picture in big picture

Comment: Just once then? It's not like a database search? E: this matters because doing it just once defeats preprocessing

Comment: No, I want to search images in thread. But yeah, one image in algorithm.

Comment: It's like doing screenshot and searching pictures on it.

Comment: It looks like Template Matching algorithm, check out http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: Template Matching is slow...